# sstable format help needed

Tags: cassandra, scylladb

It's certainly a dumb idea but I convinced myself to write a sstable decoder in Golang.

I've read [the spec here](https://opensource.docs.scylladb.com/stable/architecture/sstable/sstable3/sstables-3-data-file-format.html).

Currently I can decode the Compression file. According to this file it's pretty clear that Data files are compressed with lz4, with a 64k chunk length (which seems the C* standard).

Something like this in my example:

```
compressor_name: LZ4Compressor
option_count: 0
chunk_length: 65536
data_length: 444513368
chunk_count: 6783
chunk_offsets:
 0: 0
 1: 18929
 2: 37530
 3: 55496
 4: 73846
 5: 92385
 6: 110697
 7: 129003
 8: 147495
 9: 165637
 10: 184023
...
```

This is where I struggle. My current comprehension is that at every offset we should have a compressed lz4 block (and not frame, not trace of the lz4 magic number).

According to [this documentation](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/dev/doc/lz4_Block_format.md) the block must have metadata.

According to another documentation the first 4 bytes (littleEndian) seems to be the the uncompressed block length ; which seems OK since it's 64k in my example for the first block. (or is it the compressed size?). We could infer the uncompress size with offset from the compression file.  The 4 last bytes of each should be a checksum (things I succeed reading in the c* code). So theoretically the in-between should be lz4 compressed data block. But I have no luck in decoding them.

Any help/ pointers appreciated (I tried to read the C* code but it's still a bit convoluted for me currently)